# UV mapping in blender for use with Unreal Engine material

Tags: blender, unreal-4, uv-mapping

I have a room that I want to import in Unreal Engine 4.

[image]
When I do it, I apply a material to the walls (for example), and the walls look like this:

[image]

My question is, how can I map the object to the unreal engine material? I've seen some tutorials but I don't specifically know what I must do, since I only apply the material in Unreal.

Comment: Your mistake was not adding an image to your uv mapping to see why it looks like that.

Answer (score 1):

I guess yo don't understand UV Mapping.

Let's say you have one texture, for example a brick texture.
Since every wall should have the brick texture, you have to map all quads of the wall to the [0,1] UV Space to fit the texture.
[image]
This is the original UV setup. similar to yours.
To "distribute" the texture evenly on the faces,
you need the faces to fit in the [0,1] UV-Space.
[image]
Here I only did one side of the object.
As you can see, the left side is now properly textured.
[image]
Here I did the same for the second face.
The UVs are now overlapping!

In your example mesh, some faces don't need the [0,1] space completely. Play around until it fits your needs.
Overlapping UVs are no Problem for the texutre Channel.
You need a second UV Channel for Lightmaps. There you can't have overlapping UVs or UVs that are not in [0,1] space

For creating lightmaps (proper UV setup for them) look at this:
https://docs.unrealengine.com/latest/INT/Engine/Content/Types/StaticMeshes/LightmapUnwrapping/

Edit:
Here's an example of a mirrored UV Map:
[image]
Each side of the mesh uses the same UVs